# Explicitly polymorphic annotation in nested context

Tags: types, polymorphism, ocaml, type-inference, let

In the code below, I am not sure I understand why there is a type error on `_nested2`.

Does that mean that only toplevel definitions generalize their inferred type to match an explicitly polymorphic signature?

```ml
let toplevel1 : 'a. 'a -> int = (fun _ -> 0)
let toplevel2 : 'a. 'a -> int = (fun (_ : 'a) -> 0)

let nest1 =
  let _nested1 : 'a. 'a -> int = (fun _ -> 0) in 0

let nest2 =
  let _nested2 : 'a. 'a -> int = (fun (_ : 'a) -> 0) in 0
(*                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   Error: This definition has type 'a -> int which is less general than
            'a0. 'a0 -> int
*)
```

Comment: I wonder if this is considered higher-rank polymorphism, because the local functions can close over polymorphic variables in the outer function or something. Ref. https://ocaml.org/releases/4.13/htmlman/polymorphism.html#s:higher-rank-poly

Comment: Ah, no it's probably just that type variables defined in a type annotation isn't in scope in the definition. So the `'r`s on either side of the equal sign in `'r. 'r t -> int = fun (l': 'r t)`  are different `'r`s. Hence by adding a type annotation to the function argument you're actually telling the compiler that it's less general.

Comment: Still, I wonder why that doesn't behave the same for the top-level definition of `_toto2`

Comment: @Maëlan Although your edits to the question makes the question itself better, it's quite confusing that the answer still refer to the now non-existing code fragments `'r` and `(l: 'r t)`. Either the question or the answer ought to be edited so that the references are once again valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the `'a` type variable in the `(l': 'a t)` annotation lives in the whole toplevel definition and thus outlives the polymorphic annotation.

In order to illustrate this scope issue for type variables, consider

```ml
let int, id = 
  let f (x:'a) = x in
   (0:'a), f
```

Here, maybe surprisingly, the type of `id` ends up being `int ->int` rather than `'a. 'a -> 'a` because the type variable `'a` is shared between `(x:'a)` and `(0:'a)`.

Coming back to the issue at end, this means that it is not yet possible to generalize the type of `_nested2` on the second line of the `nest2` function due to the escaping variable `'a`.

Moreover, it is only with recent versions of OCaml (after OCaml 4.11.0) that the `toplevel2` function:

```ml
let toplevel2 : 'a. 'a -> int = (fun (_ : 'a) -> 0)
```

is accepted.

Older versions of OCaml fail with

> Error: This definition has type 'a -> int which is less general > than
> 'a0. 'a0 -> int

because the algorithm for checking explicit polymorphic annotation in earlier versions did not detect that the unification type variable is not escaping the scope of the toplevel definition.

The short version is thus that is is better to not mix explicit polymorphic annotation with (unification) type variables.

Comment: if I rephrase : because it outlives the annotation, and escapes to top level, and because of the way unification is performed, it is not generalized by the compiler (although it could in principle)

Comment: Ah, I see, the type quantifier on the let-definition does not act as a binder for a type variable of the same name in the body of the definition: `let f : 'a. 'a -> int = fun (_ : 'a) -> 0 in …` is the same as `let f : 'b. 'b -> int = fun (_ : 'a) -> 0 in …` Surprising indeed! Another use case for locally abstract types I guess: `let f : type a. a -> int = fun (_ : a) -> 0`

Comment: Yes that seems to be the (first) incorrect assumption made by OP. And (if I understand correctly) it just happens to work in the toplevel definition because there it's able to unify with the type annotation, while in the nested case it does not because the type variable escapes the definition and therefore cannot be generalized at that point. But in neither case is the type variable in the definition being constrained by the universal quantification.

Comment: I edited the answer to match my edits to the question (thanks @glennsl). The code example about “generalizing the last nested let-def” became trivial, so I edited a bit more. I rewrote the surrounding paragraph because IIUC it is a corner case in which the typechecker can avoid the general issue discussed but, unlike the paragraph seemed to imply, it doesn’t solve OP’s specific issue because the code does something different. I’m not sure I entirely understood that paragraph though (how is that not just the usual generalization of the global `let`?), so feel free to complain/revert!

Comment: Maëlan, please don't edit answers that you don't understand.

Comment: I see. It looks like I was indeed thinking about "locally abstract types" behavior, à la haskell. thank you for that keyword. I should read the language extension https://ocaml.org/manual/extn.html which I didn't yet.

Comment: This is a major difference between OCaml and Haskell: In OCaml by default type variables in annotations are unification type variables (in other words, they can always be refined).